# What's the best third party assembly to merge and compress PDF files for .NET?

Tags: c#, pdf, merge

I've tried PDFSharp but they are having issues with the latest versions of Acrobat Reader.

Does anyone know the best ones out there that are free?

I'm coding in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) easily merges PDF files.

Here is a sample that shows how to merge a number of PDFs into one.

```
using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument())
{
    string[] filesToMerge = ...
    foreach (string file in filesToMerge)
        pdf.Append(file);

    // delete the first (automatically inserted) page
    pdf.RemovePage(0);

    // document gets saved compressed by default
    // you can compress it even more if you set following options to true

    //pdf.SaveOptions.RemoveUnusedObjects = true;
    //pdf.SaveOptions.UseObjectStreams = true;

    pdf.Save("merged.pdf");
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Answer (score 0):

While not free .. have a look at Aspose, they have decent components and are good on support.  I've used them on several projects, mainly their Word offering, but did get a chance to use the PDF component they have and it was easy enough to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with [Amyuni PDF Creator .net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features)

The [Append](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.Append_Method.htm) method allows you to concatenate or insert pages of one PDF file into another.
The [Merge](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacDocument/Methods/IacDocument.Merge_Method_.htm) method allows you to draw pages of one PDF file on top of the pages of another file.

All PDF files will be saved with compression by default.

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down for the answer here:

[Merging multiple PDFs using iTextSharp in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net)

iTextSharp is the way to go!!