# How to combine 2 base64binary PDF files into Single PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, base64, arrays, filestream

In my Application I'm using some webservice that returns me a pdf file in `base64binary` format. In my code I'm getting this file as `byte[]`.

My question is how to combine 2 `byte[]` into a single and store it as pdf correctly?

So far I store each pdf file separately:

```
byte[] bytes = image.ImageData; // WebService that returns base64binary as byte[]
System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Test\" + "File_" + i + ".pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: You'll need a pdf library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could save them as separate pdfs and use `iTextSharp` to merge two pdfs...

Sample code is available in below question

[Merging multiple PDFs using iTextSharp in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net)

Comment: Thanks. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's good. It means I will do multiple steps: Store all pdf files > Combine them into single file > Delete all files that I don't need