# iTextSharp - Splitting and Merging PDF files

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a PDF template that contains a .JPG image of a signature.
When creating a batch of PDF's from that template, the signature is rendered correctly.

When I split apart the batch, the signature in the individual files appears as expected.

However, when the individual files are then remerged, the signature no longer appears.

Comment: A [Short, Self Contained, Compilable, Example](http://sscce.org/), please.

Comment: Surely you're using `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` to merge the individual files? If `PdfSmartCopy`, which version of iTextSharp are you using? There were some problems with old versions.

Comment: I am using the same MergerFiles function found on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net

Comment: Which one, the one from the question or one from the answers?