# How to merge a physical file (pdf) and a generated one (pdf) and output them to the browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Been struggling with this.

I have a physical file (pdf) and a generated one that is generated by iTextSharp (pdf) my goal is to merge both of them and output it to the browser.

By the way, I am using ASP.NET MVC 4

So, in my controller, I have something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  var path = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/../myfile.pdf"); // This is my physical file
  var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

  GenerateFile(); // This is my generated file thru iTextSharp

  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
  memoryStream.Position = 0;

  return new FileStreamResult(// Maybe merged file goes here? not sure.
                             ,"application/pdf");
}

private void GenerateFile()
{
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  var document = new Document(/*some settings here*/);
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream).CloseStream = false;

  document.Open();
  // generate pdf here
  document.Close();
}
```

And is it possible to set the generated pdf as the first (or how many pages it will generate) page then append the physical file?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: please visit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net

Comment: `var generatedFile = GenerateFile();` but `GenerateFile` returns `void`

Comment: @codroipo oh yea, that was a mistake. i'll edit it.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Thanks man, I'll try this one out

Comment: @MuhammadUsman hey man, think you can show me how to use the function? can't seem to make it work. I cant make it work with generated pdf and physical pdf

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar (merging physical and code generated PDF's) using PDFSharp if it's of any help.

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

PdfDocument physicalDoc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filepath);
PdfPage coverPage = physicalDoc.Pages[0];

document.AddPage(coverPage);
```

And then adding you own generated pages can be done as:

```
PdfPage generatedPage = new PdfPage();
XGraphics g = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(generatedPage);

g.DrawRectangle(color, x, y, width, height);  
g.DrawString("This release document describes the contents of..."
             ,font, textColor, x, y);

document.AddPage(generatedPage)
```

Comment: how would you know what page will come first?

Comment: @BoyPasmo The `Pages` array is ordered in the same way that the physical pdf is. So the first page in the PDF will be the first page in the array

Comment: How about the generated pdf? How will I add them? Sorry for this kind of questions tho

Comment: @BoyPasmo I've updated my answer to include generated pages. You will need to add the pages in the order you want them to display in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a sample for c#

First you need to instal a third party library: [pdfium.net sdk](http://pdfium.patagames.com) for example

You can do it through nuget
**Install-package pdfium.net.sdk**

```
public void MergeDocument()
{
    //Initialize the SDK library
    //You have to call this function before you can call any PDF processing functions.
    PdfCommon.Initialize();

    //Open and load a PDF document in which will be merged other files
    using (var mainDoc = PdfDocument.Load(@"c:\test001.pdf"))
    {
        //Open one PDF document.
        using (var doc = PdfDocument.Load(@"c:\doc1.pdf"))
        {
            //Import all pages from document
            mainDoc.Pages.ImportPages(
                doc,
                string.Format("1-{0}", doc.Pages.Count),
                mainDoc.Pages.Count
                );
        }

        //Open another PDF document.
        using (var doc = PdfDocument.Load(@"c:\doc2.pdf"))
        {
            //Import all pages from document
            mainDoc.Pages.ImportPages(
                doc,
                string.Format("1-{0}", doc.Pages.Count),
                mainDoc.Pages.Count
                );
        }

        mainDoc.Save(@"c:\ResultDocument.pdf", SaveFlags.NoIncremental);


    }
    //Release all resources allocated by the SDK library
    PdfCommon.Release();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that patagames offers a paid solution