# using PdfCopy to merge pdf files

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I need to add multiple pdfs (each single page) to my main pdf. These need to be added after a specific page number and not appended to the end.

How do i

1: merge the pdf at a specific page number

2: pdfCopy.AddDocument is not available. I have tested with version 5.4.3, 5.4.5 and 5.5.10. What am i missing here? All say to use 5.X which i am...

```
'PdfCopy' does not contain a definition for 'AddDocument' and no extension method 'AddDocument' accepting a first argument of type 'PdfCopy' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

3: How to handle when pageToInsert at is greater than total number of pages in the source?

I have looked at tons of docs by now. All tell to use PdfCopy and .AddDocument...

[Merging multiple PDFs using iTextSharp in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net)

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2014/01/10/simple-merging-of-pdf-documents-with-itextsharp-5-4-5.aspx

here is my first take at it....

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace PdfMergeTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string baseFile = "baseFile.tmp";
        private const string baseTempPdfFileName = "temp.pdf";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!CheckBasePaths())
                return;

            //get the files to merge to baseFile
            var filesToMerge = GetAllFilesToMerge();
            if (filesToMerge.Length == 0)
                return;

            //get basefile to which we need to merge the above files, it is with .tmp ext
            var baseFileWithPath = GetBaseFile();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseFileWithPath))
                return;

            //temp base pdf
            var tempPdfWithPath = GetBaseTempFile();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempPdfWithPath))
                return;

            //loop through the files to merge and merge into baseFile
            var page = 2; //page where to merge the file, we are not appending to the end. Actual code will find the page from source where to merge and will add 1 to it 
            foreach (FileInfo toMerge in filesToMerge)
            {
                //copy the base file as temp file for source; for debugging purposes at this time
                File.Copy(baseFileWithPath, tempPdfWithPath, true);

                //start merging, first at #2, second at #4, third at #6 and so on 
                MergeFiles(baseFileWithPath, tempPdfWithPath, toMerge.FullName, page);

                page += 2;
            } 
        }

        private bool CheckBasePaths()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBaseDir.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Base Directory");
                return false;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFilesToMergeToBase.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No files to merge Directory");
                return false;
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(txtBaseDir.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Base dir does not exist");
                return false;
            }

            if (!Directory.Exists(txtFilesToMergeToBase.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Files to merge dir does not exist");
                return false;
            }

            return true; 
        }

        private FileInfo[] GetAllFilesToMerge()
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(txtFilesToMergeToBase.Text);
            FileInfo[] files = d.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            if (files.Length == 0)
                MessageBox.Show("No files to merge");
            return files;
        }

        private String GetBaseFile()
        {
            var myBaseFile = Path.Combine(txtBaseDir.Text, baseFile);
            if (!File.Exists(myBaseFile))
            {
                myBaseFile = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Base file missing");
            }
            return myBaseFile;
        }

        private String GetBaseTempFile()
        {
            var myBaseTempFile = Path.Combine(txtBaseDir.Text, baseTempPdfFileName);
            return myBaseTempFile;
        }

        private void MergeFiles(string originalFile, string sourceFile, string toMergeFile, int insertPage)
        {
            Document document = null;
            PdfCopy pdfCopy = null;
            PdfReader pdfReader = null;

            try
            {
                //Step#1: create a document object
                document = new Document();

                //Step#2: create a writer that listen to the document
                pdfCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileStream(originalFile, FileMode.Create));
                if (pdfCopy == null)
                    return;

                //Step#3: open document
                document.Open();

                //Step#4: create a reader for the toMergeFile and add document
                pdfReader = new PdfReader(toMergeFile);
                //add the entire document instead of page by page
                pdfCopy.AddDocument(pdfReader);
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pdfReader != null) pdfReader.Close();
                if (pdfCopy != null) pdfCopy.Close();
                if (document != null) document.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at following using `.AddPage` but this is not what i want.

http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-combine-pdf-files.htm

Comment: The `AddDocument()` method is certainly present in iTextSharp 5.4.5 and 5.4.11, but it wasn't available in 5.0.0. Maybe you have different versions of iTextSharp in your environment, and maybe you're using an old version without realizing that you're using that old version. How to find out? Create a simple Hello World example, and look at the producer line (see Document Properties in Adobe Reader). That will tell you the version you are actually using.

Comment: I have setup a new test and downloaded versions 5.4.5 and 5.5.10. So the above test code is from my test project. AddDocument isn't available. Now the zip thats that i downloaded, even though is saying 5.5.10, is actually containing the old version? Can you point me to right url?

Comment: using `iTextSharp.text` and `iTextSharp.text.pdf` and the dll is pdfa. does this seems correct to you @BrunoLowagie?

Comment: When you say *and the dll is pdfa*, you confuse me. Why would you need the PDF/A DLL to merge documents??? Please follow my advice and create a simple PDF. Look at the Document Properties and check the version number mentioned in the producer line.

Comment: i was downloading the dlls from sourceforge.net and looks like those are not updated properly. I have used nuget to download 5.5.10 and it has the .AddDocument. 

Could you plz point me to an example that adds the pdfs after a particular page number in the base pdf rather than to the end? I will be running my tests in a short while as well and see if i get into any issue.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie please move your comment as an answer so that i can accept it. I'll provide my testing code, i still need to do bit cleaning but its working.

Comment: No need for me to add the comment as an answer. I see that you provided a very detailed answer. This is excellent as your answer can be used for future reference. I think that you can accept your own answer after a couple of days. I don't think that gives you extra reputation, but... well, I wouldn't worry about that.An accepted answer is worth 15 points, but so is the sum of my up-votes for your question + answer.

Comment: You have a great attitude, i have learned both a technique and a life lesson from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me... It needs bit of cleaning which will now happen after the long weekend.

```
Private Sub btnExtractMerge_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExtractMerge.Click
        txtCurSetupMessages.Text = ""
        ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Extract & Merge Process Started")

        'get and check the paths / files from the form 
        Dim baseDir As String = txtCurSetupBaseDataFolder.Text
        Dim baseInvDir As String = txtCurSetupInvoicesFolder.Text
        Dim baseFileName As String = txtEMBaseFile.Text
        Dim targetFileName As String = txtEMTargetFile.Text

        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseDir) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Base folder empty!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseInvDir) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Base invoice folder name empty!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(baseFileName) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Base file name empty!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetFileName) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Target file name empty!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not Directory.Exists(baseDir) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Base folder does not exist!")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        baseInvDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, baseInvDir)
        If Not Directory.Exists(baseInvDir) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Base invoice folder does not exist!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'get the invoice files
        Dim dirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(baseInvDir)
        Dim files As FileInfo() = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf")
        If files.Length <= 0 Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Invoices missing!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        baseFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, baseFileName)
        If Not File.Exists(baseFileName) Then
            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Base file missing!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        targetFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, targetFileName)
        If File.Exists(targetFileName) Then
            File.Delete(targetFileName)
        End If

        Dim tempSource As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, "tempSource.pdf")
        If File.Exists(tempSource) Then
            File.Delete(tempSource)
        End If

        'copy the base file as temp file
        File.Copy(baseFileName, tempSource, True)

        'do action 
        Dim iteration As Integer = 1
        Dim totalPages As Integer = 0
        Dim page As Integer = 0

        Dim temp As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, "temp.pdf")
        Dim tempBefore As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, "tempBefore.pdf")
        Dim tempAfter As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseDir, "tempAfter.pdf")
        Dim reader As PdfReader = Nothing

        For Each myFile As FileInfo In files

            If File.Exists(temp) Then File.Delete(temp)
            If File.Exists(tempBefore) Then File.Delete(tempBefore)
            If File.Exists(tempAfter) Then File.Delete(tempAfter)

            'get total pages in the pdf
            reader = New PdfReader(tempSource)
            totalPages = reader.NumberOfPages
            reader.Close()
            If totalPages = 0 Then
                ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, String.Format("0 pages found in the source file"))
                Exit For
            End If

            'find page number, this is the page after which we'll place the invoice pdf 
            page = FindPageNo(tempSource, 1, myFile.Name.ToUpper.Replace(".PDF", ""))
            If page <= 0 Then Continue For

            ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, String.Format("Processing Invoice:{0} Page:{1} InvoiceFile:{2}", Format(iteration, "000"), Format(page + 1, "000"), myFile.Name))

            If page = totalPages Then
                'append the invoice file to the end 
                AddDocuments(temp, tempSource, myFile.FullName, "")
            Else
                'divide the pages into temp before and temp after then put together
                BuildTempBeforeAndAfter(tempSource, tempBefore, tempAfter, page, totalPages)
                'now put together
                AddDocuments(temp, tempBefore, myFile.FullName, tempAfter)
            End If

            'move the temp into temp source
            If File.Exists(temp) Then
                File.Copy(temp, tempSource, True)
            End If

            iteration += 1
        Next

        'clean reader, used for temp number of pages 
        If Not reader Is Nothing Then reader.Close()

        'clean the temp files used by the loop 
        If File.Exists(temp) Then File.Delete(temp)
        If File.Exists(tempBefore) Then File.Delete(tempBefore)
        If File.Exists(tempAfter) Then File.Delete(tempAfter)

        'move temp source to target file and delete 
        If File.Exists(tempSource) Then
            File.Copy(tempSource, targetFileName, True)
            File.Delete(tempSource)
        End If

        ShowMessage(txtCurSetupMessages, "Process Completed")
    End Sub

Private Function FindPageNo(ByVal sourceFiles As String, ByVal startpage As Integer, ByVal invno As String) As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim str1 As String
        Dim pos1 As Integer, pos2 As Integer
        Dim bgReader As PdfReader
        Dim pagen As Integer
        If File.Exists(sourceFiles) Then
            bgReader = New PdfReader(sourceFiles)

            If startpage > bgReader.NumberOfPages Then
                FindPageNo = -1  'error. invalid
                bgReader.Close()
            End If

            pagen = 0
            For i = startpage To bgReader.NumberOfPages
                str1 = pdftextextractor.GetTextFromPage(bgReader, i)
                pos1 = str1.IndexOf("Invoice No:")
                pos2 = str1.IndexOf("Phone:")
                If pos2 > pos1 Then
                    If str1.Substring(pos1 + 11, pos2 - pos1 - 11).Trim.Equals(invno) = True Then
                        pagen = i  'found the page
                        'bgReader.Close()
                        'Exit Function
                    Else
                        If pagen <> 0 Then
                            'we found the page no. so no need to go further.
                            'exit now
                            FindPageNo = pagen  'last page found
                            bgReader.Close()
                            Exit Function
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            bgReader.Close()
        End If
        If pagen <> 0 Then
            FindPageNo = pagen  'last page found
        Else
            FindPageNo = 0  'not found
        End If

    End Function

    Private Function BuildTempBeforeAndAfter(ByVal tempSource As String, ByVal tempBefore As String, ByVal tempAfter As String, ByVal endPage As Integer, ByVal totalPages As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim reader As PdfReader = Nothing
        Dim copy As PdfCopy = Nothing
        Dim doc As Document = Nothing
        Dim impPage As PdfImportedPage = Nothing
        Dim isBuild As Boolean = True
        Try
            reader = New PdfReader(tempSource)
            doc = New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
            'before file
            copy = New PdfCopy(doc, New FileStream(tempBefore, FileMode.Create))
            doc.Open()
            For index = 1 To endPage
                impPage = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, index)
                copy.AddPage(impPage)
            Next
            copy.Close()
            doc.Close()
            'after file 
            doc = New Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))
            copy = New PdfCopy(doc, New FileStream(tempAfter, FileMode.Create))
            doc.Open()
            For index = endPage + 1 To totalPages
                impPage = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, index)
                copy.AddPage(impPage)
            Next
            reader.Close()
            copy.Close()
            doc.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            isBuild = False
        Finally
            'clean the objects 
            If Not reader Is Nothing Then reader.Close()
            If Not doc Is Nothing Then doc.Close()
            If Not reader Is Nothing Then reader.Close()
        End Try
        Return isBuild
    End Function

    Private Function AddDocuments(ByVal targetFile As String, ByVal addFile1 As String, ByVal addFile2 As String, ByVal addFile3 As String) As Boolean
        Dim reader As PdfReader = Nothing
        Dim copy As PdfCopy = Nothing
        Dim doc As Document = Nothing
        Dim isAdded As Boolean = True
        Try
            doc = New Document
            copy = New PdfSmartCopy(doc, New FileStream(targetFile, FileMode.Create))
            doc.Open()
            'add file 1
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addFile1) Then
                reader = New PdfReader(addFile1)
                copy.AddDocument(reader)
                reader.Close()
            End If
            'add file 2 
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addFile2) Then
                reader = New PdfReader(addFile2)
                copy.AddDocument(reader)
                reader.Close()
            End If
            'add file 3 
            If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addFile3) Then
                reader = New PdfReader(addFile3)
                copy.AddDocument(reader)
                reader.Close()
            End If
            copy.Close()
            doc.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            isAdded = False
        Finally
            'clean the objects 
            If Not reader Is Nothing Then reader.Close()
            If Not doc Is Nothing Then doc.Close()
            If Not reader Is Nothing Then reader.Close()
        End Try
        Return isAdded
    End Function
```