# Using itextsharp to merge pdf files within a folder

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to use codes below to merge the pdf files in a folder and output into a new file but apparently the generated file seems corrupted.

```
public Boolean MergeForm(String destinationFile, String sourceFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (Document doc = new Document())
            using (PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(doc, stream))
            {
                doc.Open();

                PdfReader reader = null;
                PdfImportedPage page = null;

                foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder))
                {
                    reader = new PdfReader(file);
                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                        pdf.AddPage(page);
                    }

                    pdf.FreeReader(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
                using (FileStream streamX = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.WriteTo(streamX);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone spot on where's the problem? Thank you.

Comment: This looks very much like a duplicate of the recent question [using PdfCopy to merge pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951966/using-pdfcopy-to-merge-pdf-files). Why aren't you using the `AddDocument()` method instead of looping over the different pages, and adding only one page at a time? Are you using a recent version of iText?

Comment: The main problem however, is the moment you are writing the file. When you do `stream.WriteTo(streamX)`, the `Document` instance hasn't been closed yet. This means that the PDF that is written to `streamX` is incomplete. Plenty of information (such as the cross-reference table, fonts, the PDF trailer) is missing. That information is only added to `stream` when `docClose()` happens. In your case, this happens implicitly when one of those `}` brackets *after* `stream.WriteTo(streamX)` is reached.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I'm using itextsharp 5.5.12.0.

btw, how to modify the codes to use AddDocument?

I will take a look in the another thread you sharing here, thank you.

Comment: Did you read the code in the answer I refer to? You'll find something like this: `reader = New PdfReader(file); copy.AddDocument(reader); reader.Close();` The is *no need to loop over the pages*!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Oops, I read your second comment only after writing the answer...

Comment: @mkl No problem. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone spot on where's the problem?

Your main problem is that you use the contents of the `MemoryStream` before the `Document` and `PdfCopy` have finished creating the PDF (during the `Dispose` at the end of the `using` block). Thus, you save an incomplete PDF file as a result.

Doing it like this instead should work:

```
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Document doc = new Document())
        {
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(doc, stream);
            pdf.CloseStream = false;
            doc.Open();

            PdfReader reader = null;
            PdfImportedPage page = null;

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder))
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                    pdf.AddPage(page);
                }

                pdf.FreeReader(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        using (FileStream streamX = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            stream.WriteTo(streamX);
        }
    }
```

BTW, you also see here that I did not put `PdfCopy` into a `using` block. This is because the `Document` implicitly closes the `PDFCopy` when it is disposed. First disposing the `PdfCopy` and then the `Document` (which tries to close the `PdfCopy` again), therefore, is not necessary and can result in hiding exceptions thrown from within the block by other exceptions occurring in this closing circus.

Furthermore I needed to add the `pdf.CloseStream = false`, otherwise the memory stream would have been closed when the `PdfCopy` is closed.

---

That been said,

1. Of course you should also use `AddDocument` instead of iterating over the document pages yourself as already explained by @Bruno.
2. Your memory footprint would decrease if you immediately wrote to the file stream instead of the memory stream.