# Add contents of a PDF, from the URL

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am currently assembling a PDF on iTextSharp.
It has two pages. I create it, and add text, images, etc ...

However, I need to add on the third page the content of another PDF (which comes from a URL), that content has 1 page.

Then it would be:

- Page 1 - I create content
- Page 2 - I create content
- Page 3 - content coming from a PDF

I'm not seeing a way to do this with iTextSharp, how could I take the content of a link and add it to a page?

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net will help.

Comment: In essence do it in two passes, first create a pdf with your pages 1 and 2, and then merge that pdf with the other existing pdf. Arun's link shows how to merge.